# Install Grequests (stuck on gevent) mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, gcc, cython, gevent, grequests

I try the last hours to install grequests on my mac 10.8.

When I `pip install` it I get:

```
$ pip install grequests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): grequests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking gevent (from grequests)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gevent
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hx/_6mzcrld6777n9mfkx7g9dmc0000gp/T/pip-build-ddl449/gevent/setup.py", line 95
        print 'Linking %s to %s' % (path_to_build_core_so, path_to_core_so)
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/hx/_6mzcrld6777n9mfkx7g9dmc0000gp/T/pip-build-ddl449/gevent/setup.py", line 95

    print 'Linking %s to %s' % (path_to_build_core_so, path_to_core_so)

                           ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hx/_6mzcrld6777n9mfkx7g9dmc0000gp/T/pip-build-ddl449/gevent
Storing complete log in /Users/ddl449/.pip/pip.log
```

Which seems to be a `gevent` installation problem as I get the same error when I use:

```
 pip install gevent #same with pip-3.2
```

So I went to seem how I can install gevent [manually](https://github.com/surfly/gevent#get-gevent) .
And I see as prerequisite [greenlet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) .

And I `pip install` it but I get:

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/hx/_6mzcrld6777n9mfkx7g9dmc0000gp/T//ccRlrUpW.out
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

However I have GCC:

```
$ gcc
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

Maybe I have messed up something with GCC..

Also:

```
$ sudo port install py-greenlet
Error: Port py-greenlet not found
```

So, that's how far I have gone. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I worked around the GCC error with simply compiling the tarballs `python setup.py build install`. Although I have Cython installed I get error when I try to install the `gevent` built tarball.

```
$ sudo python3.3 setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to gevent.egg-info/requires.txt
writing dependency_links to gevent.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to gevent.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing gevent.egg-info/PKG-INFO
reading manifest file 'gevent.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile.ext'
writing manifest file 'gevent.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
/usr/local/bin/python3.3 util/cythonpp.py -o gevent.core.c gevent/core.ppyx
Running cython -o gevent.core.c gevent/core.pyx  # !EV_USE_SIGNALFD && !defined(LIBEV_EMBED) && !defined(_WIN32)
sh: cython: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 801, in <module>
    process_filename(filename, options.output_file)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 85, in process_filename
    output = run_cython(pyx_filename, sourcehash, output_filename, banner, comment)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 529, in run_cython
    system(command, comment)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 539, in system
    raise AssertionError('%r failed with code %s' % (command, result))
AssertionError: 'cython -o gevent.core.c gevent/core.pyx' failed with code 32512
make: *** [gevent/gevent.core.c] Error 1
```

Comment: I know it's not stable yet, but have you tried the release candidate version of gevent 1.0.x ? All the prerequisites are self-contained. `pip install cython -e git://github.com/surfly/gevent.git@1.0rc2#egg=gevent`

Comment: @woozyking yeah I have tried this as well, now that I remember. It returns the same GCC error (`failed with exit status 1`)

Comment: This might have something to do with OS X being 64-bit / 32-bit hybrid architecture weirdness (I might be totally wrong, but it's very different from Linux distros and Windows where they define 64 bit or 32 bit with clear lines)

Comment: @woozyking I worked around the gcc problem but now it seems to be some trouble between cython and gevent. `installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg` I am wondering if that line is correct (10.6?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is all I did.
I cleared GCC which was in /usr/local/bin. Now it's in /usr/bin. I used [ggc installer package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) I don't know if that helped but I did it.

I updated to 2.7.5 (I had 2.7.2) and `pip install cython`. I was installed. The same with `gevent` and `grequest`. And done.

However `gevent` and maybe `cython` seems to break in python 3.3.